# Does Nhibernate session.BeginTransaction auto rollback on exception within Using

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

Ok sorry for the long subject name...

If I do the following:

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    // do something
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

If my *do something* caused an exception, would it auto rollback, or do I need to explicitly check for this like below:

```
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        // do something
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a safe assumption that the transaction will be rolled back if the commit fails in a using block.

`ITransaction` wraps an ADO.NET transaction behind the scenes, so it depends on the provider specific implementation. The `Dispose` method in the source code I checked (2.1) assumes that calling `Dispose` on the internal `IDbTransaction` rolls it back.

Comment: So the first code example is fine to use? I am using SQL Server and Mysql as providers (based on underlying config), so i presume thats using ADO.

Comment: The first code sample is fine to use and will rollback the transaction if the commit fails.